# Command-line command to append white space to regex match

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I want to add whitespace to each match of a regex pattern found in a text file.

Example:

```
xadsfa 1 - 2 --- --- --- AB
jklhwj 3 --- --- --- asdfh
weriulceh 2 - 4 --- --- --- asdf
```

I want to match '1 -2' or '2 - 4'. I've come up with this pattern:

```
[0-9]\s-\s[0-9]
```

Now I'd like to append a white space to each match, like this:

```
xadsfa 1 - 2  --- --- --- AB
jklhwj 3 --- --- --- asdfh
weriulceh 2 - 4  --- --- --- asdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial with a tool like `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\s-\s[0-9]/& /' file
xadsfa 1 - 2  --- --- --- AB
jklhwj 3 --- --- --- asdfh
weriulceh 2 - 4  --- --- --- asdf
```

The `s/foo/bar/` operator will replace the first occurrence of `foo` with `bar` on each line of the input file. If you want to match *all* cases on a given line, use `g`: `s/foo/bar/g`. The `&` is "whatever was matched", so `s/[0-9]\s-\s[0-9]/& /` will replace the first match of your regex with whatever was matched plus a single space.

Note that, if you're just matching a single space (not tabs or other whitespace), there's no reason to use `\s`. Just use spaces:

```
sed 's/[0-9] - [0-9]/& /' file
```

Finally, to make the changes in the file itself, use `-i` (this assumes GNU `sed`, the syntax is slightly different on other implementations; also, this will replace your file with the result of the sed operation. Make sure it does what you need before adding `-i`):

```
sed -i 's/[0-9] - [0-9]/& /' file
```